# Send Magento order confirmation after payment

Tags: magento, checkout, confirmation-email

here's my problem:
When a customer in my Magento store places an order, the confirmation mail is beeing sended right away. Even when the payment procedure is not done.

I want the order confirmation mail only to be sended when the payment is done. For example when someone chooses PayPal and clicks on Place Order button, the person is redirected to PayPal, makes the payment: confirmation mail send. But when the person is cancelling the payment in PayPal, nothing should be sended.

I did not find a solution on Google or Stackoverflow, so I hope someone can help me out. Thanks in advance!

Best Regards,

Peter

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

I face same problem. I find temporary solution for this problem.

1. Go to System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Sales Emails
   There is in Order tab order confirmation email select **NO**
2. Then Set custom email to your success payment page.

   [Please refer this link for set custom email](http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-checkout-cart-how-to-send-email-after-successful-checkout/)

Comment: Thanks. I still need the BCC to my admin e-mail. Not sure if that works here.